# Show any failed servers in the output

Tags: vbscript

I am running a VBScript to show the DNS and WINS settings on hundreds of Windows 2000 or Windows 2003 hosts. When the script has finished, I want to know at a glance if any servers are unable to run the script / cannot connect. (I am looking for something similar to the PowerShell `catch` block if possible)

The script is below

```
Const FILEPATH = "C:\users\"
'Get the input file
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsoFile = FSO.GetFile(FILEPATH & "servers.txt")
strFilePath = fsoFile.Path
Set fsoInput = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, 1)

Do While Not fsoInput.AtEndOfStream
    ComputerName = fsoInput.ReadLine
    Call showdnswins(ComputerName)
Loop

Sub showdnswins(ComputerName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & ComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
    Set config = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")
    For Each conf In config
        WScript.Echo vbNewLine, "Host name is " & conf.dnshostname
        WScript.Echo "WINS Primary is " & conf.winsprimaryserver
        WScript.Echo "WINS Secondary is " & conf.winssecondaryserver
        For Each strDNSServer In conf.DNSServerSearchOrder
            WScript.Echo "DNS order is " & strDNSServer
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

At the moment any failures are unreported, and identifying them out of hundreds of servers is time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing similar to `catch` in VBScript. You have to implement the error handling yourself.

```
On Error Resume Next  'enable error handling
some statement
If Err Then
  'error handling and/or reporting goes here
  Err.Clear
End If
other statement
If Err Then
  'error handling and/or reporting goes here
  Err.Clear
End If
...
On Error Goto 0       'disable error handling
```

In your particular case you probably want to check if the WMI connection produced an error and return the status:

```
Function showdnswins(ComputerName)
  On Error Resume Next
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & ComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
  If Err Then
    showdnswins = False
    Exit Function
  End If
  ...
  showdnswins = True
End Function
```

so that you can process the information in your `Do` loop:

```
Do Until fsoInput.AtEndOfStream
  ComputerName = fsoInput.ReadLine
  If Not showdnswins(ComputerName) Then
    WScript.Echo ComputerName & " is not available."
  End If
Loop
```

If you need more detailed error information you could have the function return a numeric status code or an object with detailed error information instead of a boolean value. Or you could add some error logging to the function itself.

To get information about failed servers at one glance it's probably best to separate error from success output, for instance by writing that error and success information to different log files and echoing at most one of them, so they're not getting mixed up.

Another option, since you're probably running the script with `cscript.exe`, is to write error information to `StdErr` and success information to `StdOut`:

```
WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "some error message"
WScript StdOut.WriteLine "regular information
```

Then you can redirect the output on the console by using the redirection operators `>` (for `StdOut`) and `2>` (for `StdErr`):

```
cscript your.vbs >out.txt 2>error.log
```